# Logstash if message is empty, drop the entire row

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a scenario where my Log messages are empty in a few cases:
[image]

**So what I want to do is, If message is empty, then drop the whole row.** Not just the field.

I tried

```
filter {
      if [Message] == "" {
        drop { }
      }
    }
```

which eliminated all the message field , which is not what i want.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide more details like where you calling filter and what drop is doing etc

Comment: What you want to do? Share an example of your log data, what you trying to do, what is the expected result and what is not working. The `drop` filter remove the event, it is not you mean when you say whole row?